# How many threads do I really need?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

I'm building a Java application with a GUI and a socket-based server, and I'm constantly running into problems with one part of the application getting stuck waiting for the other (mostly the GUI waiting for the server - no surprise there. The few times I manage to avoid these errors, I instead find myself reaching the end of my `main` method almost instantly after startup. (The app may or may not keep running, depending on if there is any GUI visible or not, but I though the `main` method wasn't supposed to return until the program is actually exiting...)

My requirements on the application are the following:

- It should be able to handle an unspecified number of clients simultaneously
- Communication between server and clients can go in either direction, and not necessarily every other turn; sometimes the server sends a bunch of messages and get replies from only some clients, other times it's the other way around.
- It should never be "too late" for a client to connect - the serversocket needs to keep accepting connections continuously for as long as the server app is running.
- During the whole time, the GUI should be unaffected by the server and clients waiting for eachother. Updates to the GUI happens through event listeners on other objects (mostly the model) which are changed by the background threads.

I've tried with the following, but I can't seem to get it right.

- 1 thread for the `main` method and the "regular" work performed by objects it creates (Controller, Model etc). This is the thread I sometimes have problems with because it *doesn't* hold anywhere and returns from `main` prematurely.
- Using `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... });` I perform all actual GUI manipulation on the UI thread, but none of these calls are "surviving" threads, so they basically just work asynchronically off the main thread.
- 1 thread for the `ServerSocket` to be able to keep listening for new connections.
- 1 thread for each client, to be able to listen to messages from clients. I'm unsure here if I need another thread here as well, to be able to send messages "out of order", i.e. without waiting to receive one first.

I have never written a (real) multithreaded application before, so this is entirely new ground to me. However, I refuse to beleive that this problem has not been solved successfully before - even so many times that some sort of best practices have evolved.

What are they? What is a good architecture for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many and varied answers to this question, but the best rule I can think of is that you need one UI thread (you haven't said what you're using for GUI, but you mentioned `invokeLater`, so I'm thinking Swing) and then one or more threads for handling clients. A thread for each client is unnecessary; use [`java.nio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) classes for asynchronous I/O instead. You may want to make the total number of client-handling threads something you can configure at runtime; the range will be fairly small, like one to four.

The machine on which you're running your application, if it's truly a server, will probably be able to handle four (e.g., a dual dual-core machine) to sixteen (quad quad-core) actual concurrent threads of execution (there are obviously server-class machines that have even more cores than that, but you get the idea), and of course you're sharing those with all of the other services running on the architecture. So having lots and lots of threads just causes lots and lots of context switching. Context switching is cheap, but nowhere near free, and if avoidable it's time the CPU could more usefully be doing something else.

For an example of a server application coded to handle lots of clients with a minimum of threads, using NIO, you might look at the source code for [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty). In fact, you might even look at just using Netty and building your application logic around its handling of the I/O.

---

Side note:

> The app may or may not keep running, depending on if there is any GUI visible or not, but I though the main method wasn't supposed to return until the program is actually exiting...

`main` will end as soon as you let it end. The JVM will keep running as long as there are outstanding running threads. If you want `main` to wait for other threads before exiting, use [`Thread#join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to join them. `join` causes the current thread to wait until the thread you call `join` on terminates (some overloads of `join` offer a timeout so the calling thread can resume if the called thread doesn't terminate within a given period of time). Compare the output of the following when you run it with no arguments vs. running it with an argument (any argument, the content of the argument doesn't matter):

```
public class JoinExample implements Runnable {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new JoinExample());

        System.out.println("Starting thread");
        t.start();

        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("Joining thread");
            while (t.isAlive()) {
                try {
                    t.join();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("main exiting");
    }

    public void run() {
        long    stop = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;

        System.out.println("Thread starting");
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < stop) {
            // Sleep a mo
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(250);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            System.out.println("Thread still running");
        }
        System.out.println("Thread stopping");
    }
}
```

All of that said, you may well want to allow the `main` thread to die, since the UI thread will be the event dispatcher thread created by Swing. More info on threads and swing [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html) and [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html).

Comment: I had never heard about `java.nio.*` (after all, my only real non-cowboy Java education was a basic programming course in my first year of my bachelor's... and a class in desing patterns that was in Java out of convenience. The teacher's convenience, of course...) but after reading up a little this definitely seems like the way to go. Thanks!